# Unable to Checkout worktree

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I tried to clone a private repository in my desktop, which has been given access to me. But while cloning I get an Fatal error like the following

[image]

Does this failure is because of the error: invalid path?, Or is something else going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The filename `Nunito-Bold.eot?` is causing your problem.

Presumably this repo is maintained on Linux (or Unix variant) where the question mark character (`?`) is allowed in files names, but you are cloning on an OS that doesn't allow the `?` character in the filename (e.g. Windows). [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1976007/184546) about allowed characters.

Perhaps you can see about getting that file (and others if applicable) renamed, or else use another OS for the clone. (Consider WSL if you're on Windows.)

Comment: Hey there!. Thank you for your suggestion. So after installing WSL and enabling linux subsystem, shall I try the cloning process?. Will that succeed, or should I do any other intermediate steps?

Comment: @DoubleH I think cloning from within WSL will work. I just tested creating a file with a question mark character in it from within WSL and it worked. BUT, I also tried creating a file from Git Bash and it worked too, so I would try cloning from Git Bash first and see if that works. You may not need WSL at all. Let me know how it goes and I'll update the answer.

Comment: okay!, I'll check that

Comment: It didn't work. The same error occurred in git bash too.